# FirebaseApp.configure() crashes app on launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, crash, config

I'm working on a iOS project which uses Firebase for analytics, crashlytics and remote config fetching. For dependency management I use cocoapods and current version of Firebase in project is the latest - `6.22.0`.

The problem here is that the app crashes on every new launch on the line of code which configures Firebase (ObjC -> `[FIRApp configure];`). I already saw a few similar posts but none of them helps in my case, unless I'm missing something.

Part of structure of project is showed on the image below. Red colour indicates main `xcodeproj` file of main target and the app. Blue colour indicates `xcodeproj` file of a custom framework which contains helpers including `FirebaseAnalytics` wrapper for analytics logging which means it has its dependency `pod Firebase/Analytics`. This custom framework is used in the main app target marked with red colour. (After `pod install` I always open `xcworkspace`, so this is in `xcworkspace`).

[image]

Below are defined pods for every project/target in `Podfile`.

```
target 'TheApp' do
    platform :ios, '11.0'
    project 'TheApp/TheApp.xcodeproj'
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
end

target 'TheCustomFramework' do
    platform :ios, '11.0'
    project 'TheCustomFramework/TheCustomFramework.xcodeproj'
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
end
```

I've added Firebase configuration method in app delegate as it's showed in google documentation.

[image]

Also, I've added `GoogleService-Info.plist` file in project as stated by google documentation.

[image]

But the app keeps crashing on Firebase configuration called in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in `AppDelegate`. When I enter deeper in stuck trace I get crash on `364th` line of code in Firebase library marked with red rectangle:

[image]

The exception message for this crash in Xcode console is:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.firebase.installations', reason: 'The default FirebaseApp instance must be configured before the defaultFirebaseApp instance can be initialized. One way to ensure that is to call `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) in the App Delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` (`application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` in Swift).'
```

What could be the issue here? Thanks for your help and answers.

p.s. sorry for the long post.

Comment: If this is a Swift project as indicated by the Swift tag in the question, not ObjC. Remove `[FIRApp configure];` and replace it with `FirebaseApp.configure()`. However it looks like it may be ObjC from the screen shot. It’s a good idea to include code and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Lastly, images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question.

Comment: It is not a Swift project. Some code is written in ObjC and some in Swift. I've updated tags.

Comment: You may want to go back through the Getting Started Guide [setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup). You're podfile doesn't match the documentation *The Firebase iOS library Firebase/Core is no longer needed.*. I also don't see `@import Firebase;` and it looks like you have two different targets/projects?If you can clarify further we may be able to help.

Comment: I've removed `Firebase/Core pods' from project and still getting the same result as before. Also, I added `@import Firebase;` into file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer my own question. I have solved this issue basically by removing `Firebase/Core pod` from every project/target in `Podfile` and add everything Firebase related to the main app target including `Firebase/Analytics pod` (that means removing it from every other project/target).

After running `pod install` I moved all files that used FirebaseAnalytics from custom framework to the main project (target). Now everything works as expected and calling `[FIRApp configure];` does not crash the application.

`Podfile` now looks something like this:

```
target 'TheApp' do
    platform :ios, '11.0'
    project 'TheApp/TheApp.xcodeproj'
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
end

target 'TheCustomFramework' do
    platform :ios, '11.0'
    project 'TheCustomFramework/TheCustomFramework.xcodeproj'
    use_frameworks!
end
```

Comment: Awesome. Glad my comment helped!

Comment: Thanks bro. You did it.